# Watching Typescript in NPM modules

Tags: typescript

I'm considering refactoring my TypeScript into a bunch of NPM modules.  But one of the things I'm worried about is keeping the JS up to date across all of these.  The issue is that I'll probably be editing code in this NPM modules.  I can setup links from `node_modules` to the "live" NPM modules.  But the question is how to keep all of them up to date?

The use case is that I'm working on my main app (written in TypeScript as well) and it depends on several modules in `node_modules`.  I might find an issue in one of those modules so I go to the TS code for that module and I want to update it.  But this is all for a front end app so I'd like to "watch" all the code and rebuild.  Typical example would be using `webpack` to bundle the front end app.  It's watch is smart enough to notice changes in the JS code and re-bundle.  But I don't think it would make sense to have the webpack configuration for my application setup to re-transpile modules.  I could run `tsc -w` but it seems like I'd have to have a running instance for each of my modules which seems pretty awkward?

Are there any clever ways to keep all this stuff up to date?  Just curious if I've missed something.  I suppose some IDEs will be smart enough to handle some of this.  But I'd prefer something that is command-line and IDE agnostic.

Comment: I use atom-typescript for ntypescript sub module in atom-typescript : Docs https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript `Easier to muck around with the compiler / language service when installed from NPM. Just open any file from node_modules/ntypescript/src folder in atom-typescript and press f6 to get a new local rebuild.`

Comment: So I assume the basic idea here is that you have a `tsconfig.json` file and then you just need to run `tsc` and it will take care of compiling everything.  And `F6` just runs `tsc` with the appropriate `tsconfig.json` file for the file you are currently editing?

To be clear, you still end up having to manually trigger rebuilds here, right?  And you are just using a feature of `atom-typescript` to make it as simple as possible in this case, if I understand correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: There is `buildOnSave` option ... but don't recommend it for large projects

Comment: After finding `linklocal` on NPM, I'm wondering the same thing, but for Babel transpiling. I get the feeling this usage just isn't supported by any build tool. Did you figure something out?

Comment: I never found a good solution.  For now, when I change one of the linked NPM modules, I just do a `tsc` in that directory.  Fortunately, `webpack -w` will see that change (if I do an `npm link`) and recompile.